# Android: Display camera still capture on TextureView Quickly?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, camera

I'm using the Android Camera2 API to take still capture images and displaying them on a TextureView (for later image editing).

I have been scouring the web for a faster method to:

1. Decode Camera Image buffer into bitmap
2. Scale bitmap to size of screen and rotate it (since it comes in rotated 90 degrees)
3. Display it on a texture view

Currently I've managed an execution time of around 0.8s for the above, but this is too long for my particular application.

A few solutions I've considered were:

1. Simply taking a single frame of the preview (timing-wise this was fast, except that I had no control over auto flash)
2. Trying to get instead a YUV_420_888 formatted image and then somehow turning that into a bitmap (there's a lot of stuff online that might help but my initial attempts bore no fruit as of yet)
3. Simply sending a reduced quality image from the camera itself, but from what I've read it looks like the [JPEG_QUALITY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#JPEG_QUALITY) parameter in CaptureRequests does nothing! I've also tried setting BitmapFactory options [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) but without any noticeable improvement in speed.
4. Finding some way to directly manipulate the jpeg byte array from image buffer to transform it and then converting to bitmap, all in one shot

For your reference, the following code takes the image buffer, decodes and transforms it, and displays it on the textureview:

```
Canvas canvas = mTextureView.lockCanvas();
// obtain image bytes (jpeg) from image in camera fragment
// mFragment.getImage() returns Image object
ByteBuffer buffer = mFragment.getImage().getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(bytes);
// decoding process takes several hundred milliseconds
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
mFragment.getImage().close();

// resize horizontally oriented images
if (src.getWidth() > src.getHeight()) {
    // transformation matrix that scales and rotates
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    if (CameraLayout.getFace() == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
        matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
    }
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    matrix.postScale(((float) canvas.getWidth()) / src.getHeight(),
        ((float) canvas.getHeight()) / src.getWidth());
    // bitmap creation process takes another several hundred millis!
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
}
// post canvas to texture view
mTextureView.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

This is my first question on stack overflow, so I apologize if I haven't quite followed common conventions.
Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing with this is to draw it into a View, and won't be saving it, have you tried to simply request JPEGs that are lower resolution than maximum, and match the screen dimensions better?

Alternatively, if you need the full-size image, JPEG images typically contain a thumbnail - extracting that and displaying it is a lot faster than processing the full-resolution image.

In terms of your current code, if possible, you should avoid having to create a second Bitmap with the scaling. Could you instead place an ImageView on top of your TextureView when you want to display the image, and then rely on its built-in scaling?
Or use Canvas.concat(Matrix) instead of creating the intermediate Bitmap?

Comment: The Canvas.concat sounds like a great idea, I'll definitely try that out.

Comment: Also, I figured out a way to request a smaller image and thus forgo the scaling, which dramatically helped with speeding things up so I think I've got it down good.